# unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, file-upload, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a secure multi-file upload script for a private cloud storage system. I dont know what I have done is any good as I started learning php 3 weeks ago.

I keep getting an error on line 59: `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir));`
and I dont know where I am going wrong. If someone can help me that woud be great.

**This is my html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PHP/Click_Upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000000000" />
Send this file: <input id="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

**This is my php**

```
<?php
// Folder for upload files
$upload_dir = "../../SeagateHDD/Uploads";

//allowed file extensions
$allowed_types = array(
/* images extensions */
'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif', 'tiff', 'jpg',
/* audio extensions */
'mp3', 'wav', 'aac', 'wma', 'm4a',
/* movie extensions */                              
'mov', 'flv', 'mpeg', 'mpg', 'mp4', 'avi', 'wmv',
/* document extensions */                               
'txt', 'pdf', 'ppt', 'pps', 'xls', 'doc', 'xlsx', 'pptx', 'ppsx', 'docx'
                        );

//Mime types not accectped
$mime_type_black_list= array(
/* Audio Mime Types */
'audio/basic', 'audio/L24', 'audio/ogg', 'audio/opus', 'audio/vorbis', 
'audio/vnd.rn-realaudio', 'audio/vnd.wave', 'audio/webm', 'audio/example',
/* Images Mime Type */
'image/vnd.djvu', 'image/example',
/* Message Mime Type*/
'message/http', 'message/imdn+xml', 'message/partial', 'message/rfc822', 
'message/example',
/* 3D Model Mime Type*/
'model/iges', 'model/mesh', 'model/vrml', 'model/x3d+binary', 
'model/x3d+fastinfoset', 'model/x3d-vrml','model/x3d+xml', 'model/example'
                            );
//checks
if(isset($_FILES['submit'])){

//loop thought all the files
foreach ($_FILES ['submit']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

//check files are not bigger than 100MB
if ($file_size > 100000000){
        echo('File size must be less than 100MB');
}

// convert file name to lowercase and explode the file and look at the extension
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name'][$key])));

//check to see if file extension is accpeted
if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_types)=== false);
    echo('File extension not accepted');

//check files with mime types
if(in_array($file_ext, $mime_type_black_list)=== true);
    echo('File mime type not accepted')

//move files from temp to choosen directory
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir)); 
     {
     echo ("File Uploaded");
     } 
     else {
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
     }
  }
}

<?php
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon after `echo('File mime type not accepted')`

Comment: Please post the error message you are receiving :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing semicolon on line 55 after `echo('File mime type not accepted')` And you also have one semicolon on line 58, that should not be there.

You should delete all semicolons after if statement.

Comment: Didn't know about the `;` after `if` lol.. strange syntax. Should be removed imo

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the line above `echo('File mime type not accepted')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` at the end of the `if`,

where it should not be there.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir)); 
{
    // ... 
}
```

You should generally use the proper if usage

```
if (...)
{
}
```

Not something with `;` or without `{ }`, even if only 1 line in the case.

Comment: You can have semicolon after if statement. It does not make sense, but it does not cause error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not only missing semicolon in line 55 but also adding redundant one in line 58 where there should be `{`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem itself has the solution

```
 unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Means you have missed a semicolon.

```
if(in_array($file_ext, $mime_type_black_list)=== true);
   echo('File mime type not accepted');
```

and also

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir))
```

which doesn't require a semicolon. Please use a good code editor which will highlight these syntax errors. That is better than posting the question and get more down votes.